# C# web api condition to check if same function was called with same params

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api in C#.

There is a function which can be called a few times from client (asynchronized of-course) with same param.

What I need is a way to check if the function was just called with same params and if so, skip some code. (heavy action which there is no need to do it twice)

I tried to add a list to the **HttpContext.Current.Appliction**, and in the start of the function check if the list contains this param:

1. If contains - skip it.
2. If not - add the param to the list and perform the action

at the end of the function, remove the the param from the list.

However, this didn't work as the code is being called from a few different places in the client (asynchronized).

So - sometimes it comes to the "if" line and the param is not in the list yet, but then **before** it adds the param to the list it reaches the "if" line again from the second call, so the param is not in the list yet, so both of them are "true" and both gets into the if.

```
    public void DoAction(string param)
    {
        try
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Application["CurrentDoActionParams"] == null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Application.Add("CurrentDoActionParams", new List<string>());
            }
            if (!((List<string>)HttpContext.Current.Application["CurrentDoActionParams"]).Contains(param))
            {
                ((List<string>)HttpContext.Current.Application["CurrentDoActionParams"]).Add(param);
                //.....
                //do heavy action here
                //.....
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Application["CurrentDoActionParams"] != null)
            {
                if (((List<string>)HttpContext.Current.Application["CurrentDoActionParams"]).Contains(param))
                {
                    ((List<string>)HttpContext.Current.Application["CurrentDoActionParams"]).Remove(param);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Is there a way to achieve this? What is the correct way?

Comment: you must handle the repeat condition at api calling end.

Answer (score 1):

Can you implement a cache, and set a suitable expiration option?

Your action can then check the cache to see if the item already exists and return it; if not present it can perform the necessary actions to generate a fresh item for the user, then add it to the cache.

Answer (score 1):

application level a cache is a good way to ensure this.

an example is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/caching-in-net-framework-applications

the key could be the name of the method with the specific parameter values.
If your method for example looks something like this :

```
public int MyMethod(int firstParam, int secondParam)
```

then your cache key, when you call the method with values 3,4 could be:

```
MyMethod_3_4
```

and the data is whatever the result of that method is. This way when the method is called, you get the key, you go check the cache ....

- is it there? get the data from cache using the unique key
- it isn't there, so go run the method, get the data and cache it.

Make your cache expire after whatever value makes sense to you.

Now, only do this if you do not have many methods and huge amounts of data.

If you want to store considerably more data then use a dedicated caching system, something like Redis, NCache or whatever else you deem appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you're doing it that way I'd recommend a `HashSet<string>` as the lookup will be faster and it is designed for this kind of thing.  Make sure you put a lock around checking and adding stuff to the hash set.

@marhls suggested a cache, and this is pretty easy to do [and comes out of the box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.caching.cache?view=netframework-4.8).  Just make sure that, if something is not in the cache, use a `lock` when adding it so that you don't get the apparent race-conditions you're currently experiencing.